# PHP Syntax highlighter is not working properly

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

Stack Overflow's syntax highlighter is not working properly if I add `php` syntax in-between `HTML`. I checked in other markdown editors and it is working fine.

#### Not Working (PHP)

```php
<picture>
  <source
    srcset="/asset/images/image-240X200.jpg"
    media="(min-width: <?php $size ?>)"
  />
  <img src="/asset/images/image-298X332.jpg" />
</picture>
```

```php
<picture>
  <source srcset="/asset/images/image-240X200.jpg" media="(min-width: <?php $size ?>)" />
  <img src="/asset/images/image-298X332.jpg" />
</picture>
```

#### Working (PHP - Only with plain HTML syntax)

```php
<picture>
  <source
    srcset="/asset/images/image-240X200.jpg"
    media="(min-width: 800px)"
  />
  <img src="/asset/images/image-298X332.jpg" />
</picture>
```

```php
<picture>
  <source srcset="/asset/images/image-240X200.jpg" media="(min-width: 800px)" />
  <img src="/asset/images/image-298X332.jpg" />
</picture>
```

[image: The source tag is not highlighted when it contains PHP code.]
[image: The highlighting breaks in both the light and dark theme.]

Comment: Related (not duplicate): *[Google Code Prettify has been officially discontinued; it's time for SE to maintain their own highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347738)* (2020-05-11)

Comment: How is the duplicate an answer? Is it a bug? A limitation (implementation choice by Stack Overflow?)? The version used by Stack Overflow is out of date compared to the Google's version? It doesn't say anything about template languages.

Comment: After this was posted, [Stack Exchange changed from Google Code Prettify to highlight.js](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter). If there's a problem with the new highlighter, then a new [meta-tag:bug] report should be filed.

Answer (score -8):

Replace : `<?php echo $size; ?>`
with : `<?php echo $size; ?>`

Comment: Both of those are the same?

Comment: A copy-paste error? In any case, an explanation would be in order. From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Thanks in advance.